# If qubits' amplitude can be a complex number, then how can we negative probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-states

We have this equation to describe a qubit ${\displaystyle |\psi \rangle =\alpha |0\rangle +\beta |1\rangle }$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are amplitudes and can be complex numbers.
We also have $\alpha^{2}$ is the probability of the qubit collapse into zero, the same with $\beta$. But $\alpha$ can and mostly be a complex number then $\alpha$ can be a negative number.
For example, $\alpha$ is $i$ then our probability is $i^2$ which is $-1$. Then how can we have negative probability?

Comment: Your question lacks elementary research; check Wikipedia or any intro textbook on QM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a physical system is in the state$^1$ $|\psi\rangle$, the probability of measuring it in the state $|\phi\rangle$ is not $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle^2$, but $\big|\langle \phi|\psi\rangle\big|^2$, which is discussed in introductory Quantum Mechanics textbooks. Hence, the probability in your example with $\alpha = i$ is not $\alpha^2 = -1$, but rather $|\alpha|^2 = 1$.

---

$^1$ I'm assuming the states to be normalized ($\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = 1$) when writing the expression for the probability.